# Will my UK employer continue to pay me under furlough during my notice period?

Tags: new-job, resignation, united-kingdom, furlough

If I resign now and give 4 weeks notice will my current employer still pay me under the furlough scheme?

I would be starting my new job in May as an NHS call handler.

Comment: Are you sure the new job will be there then? Is it some industry benefitting of the crisis?

Comment: At the very least, you're going to have to tell us which country you're in.

Comment: Don't resign. You won't get paid furlough (unless your former employer really really likes you). And your new employer will just delay your starting date indefinitely (unless it's a hospital or something). Just browse this forum, it's riddled with people that had job offers rescinded or postponed indefinitely after having  given notice to their current employer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Am I eligible to be placed on furlough after resigning?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/156626/am-i-eligible-to-be-placed-on-furlough-after-resigning)

Comment: Your country, please.

Comment: Apologies I am in London and the job is a nhs 111 call handler

Comment: Apologies to those who voted to close this as off-topic. I had cast a binding close vote waiting for OP to provide details without realising he had just commented with those. Since I reopened those close votes were cleared. Please cast them again if you feel this is still off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

In your particular situation (call handler at the U.K. National Health I'd first check if you can’t start that new job earlier. Like tomorrow.

Check how much notice your employer has to give you legally / according to your contract. And check if they are decent people. If not, you give notice at the last possible moment (when it’s legally required). If yes, talk to them. Obviously if they want you to work you’ll have to work during your notice period- and get paid. If not, a good employer will put you on furlough.

What is legal is quite unclear at the moment. For example, if your employer puts you on furlough for two months, there is no reason why you shouldn’t be able to leave without notice (you’re not working anyway).